# Android Bluetooth scans for classic AND BTLE Devices when not supposed to

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

The android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) states:

> Note: You can only scan for Bluetooth LE devices or scan for Classic Bluetooth devices, as described in Bluetooth. You cannot scan for both Bluetooth LE and classic devices at the same time.

However I am noticing that calling `mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();` is returning both classic and btle devices. Does anybody know what is correct here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From my understanding what the documentation means is that you cannot have a [startLeScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) and a [startDiscovery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) running at the same time. The reason might be that there is only one BluetoothAdapter object (the object that represents the local Bluetooth hardware) therefor it cannot do two different operations that use the BluetoothAdapter at the same time.(If someone knows anything different as to how it works in the background, let us know)

startLeScan() -> scans only for BLE devices

startDiscovery() -> discovers all Bluetooth devices, also it only scans for 12 seconds and this cannot be changed (have a read through the method description)

**Note:** After doing a startDiscovery() inquiry scan when a BT device is found you can get the device type to identify what each device is, For example:

```java
int deviceType = device.getType();
if (deviceType == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC) {

} else if (deviceType == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE) {

} else if (deviceType == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_DUAL) {    

} else if (deviceType == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the documentation is wrong. I just did a scan using startDiscovery() and it returns both classic, LE and dual devices.

Comment: After further investigation, I'm finding that while `startDiscovery()` does find BLE devices,  `startLeScan()` finds them more reliably.

Comment: @ThomasW the startDiscovery() can find all devices, it's the startLeScan() that can only see BLE devices

Answer (score -2):

```
           device: BluetoothDevice

           when (device.type) {
                1 -> edt.text = "DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC"
                2 -> edt.text = "DEVICE_TYPE_LE"
                3 -> edt.text = "DEVICE_TYPE_DUAL"
                else -> edt.text = "DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN"
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked...